# Why is the first parameter of sctp_inet_listen struct socket* instead of int

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel

I want to study the source code of the kernel network part to understand how the network part of the kernel works.But when I looked at the listen function, I found the above problem. Use man to see that the first parameter of the listen function is int.
int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);
But in https://github.com/torvalds/linux, the first parameter of the sctp_inet_listen function is struct socket*，In protocol.c we know listen is a function pointer of sctp_inet_listen

```
static const struct proto_ops inet_seqpacket_ops = {
    .family        = PF_INET,
    .owner         = THIS_MODULE,
    .release       = inet_release,  /* Needs to be wrapped... */
    .bind          = inet_bind,
    .connect       = sctp_inet_connect,
    .socketpair    = sock_no_socketpair,
    .accept        = inet_accept,
    .getname       = inet_getname,  /* Semantics are different.  */
    .poll          = sctp_poll,
    .ioctl         = inet_ioctl,
    .gettstamp     = sock_gettstamp,
    .listen        = sctp_inet_listen,
    .shutdown      = inet_shutdown, /* Looks harmless.  */
    .setsockopt    = sock_common_setsockopt, /* IP_SOL IP_OPTION is a problem */
    .getsockopt    = sock_common_getsockopt,
    .sendmsg       = inet_sendmsg,
    .recvmsg       = inet_recvmsg,
    .mmap          = sock_no_mmap,
    .sendpage      = sock_no_sendpage,
};
```

```
int sctp_inet_listen(struct socket *sock, int backlog)
{
    struct sock *sk = sock->sk;
    struct sctp_endpoint *ep = sctp_sk(sk)->ep;
    int err = -EINVAL;

    if (unlikely(backlog < 0))
        return err;

    lock_sock(sk);

    /* Peeled-off sockets are not allowed to listen().  */
    if (sctp_style(sk, UDP_HIGH_BANDWIDTH))
        goto out;

    if (sock->state != SS_UNCONNECTED)
        goto out;

    if (!sctp_sstate(sk, LISTENING) && !sctp_sstate(sk, CLOSED))
        goto out;

    /* If backlog is zero, disable listening. */
    if (!backlog) {
        if (sctp_sstate(sk, CLOSED))
            goto out;

        err = 0;
        sctp_unhash_endpoint(ep);
        sk->sk_state = SCTP_SS_CLOSED;
        if (sk->sk_reuse || sctp_sk(sk)->reuse)
            sctp_sk(sk)->bind_hash->fastreuse = 1;
        goto out;
    }

    /* If we are already listening, just update the backlog */
    if (sctp_sstate(sk, LISTENING))
        WRITE_ONCE(sk->sk_max_ack_backlog, backlog);
    else {
        err = sctp_listen_start(sk, backlog);
        if (err)
            goto out;
    }

    err = 0;
out:
    release_sock(sk);
    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, the C library function [`listen(fd,backlog)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) corresponds to a syscall (`SYS_listen`) with the same prototype.  This syscall is implemented in [net/socket.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/socket.c) (see `SYSCALL_DEFINE2(listen, int, fd, int, backlog)`).  It calls net/socket.c:__sys_listen().

net/socket.c:__sys_listen() looks up the socket description (which is of type `struct socket`) by looking up the file description table entry `fd`, and does basic checks and bookkeeping work.

The `struct socket` structure contains member `ops`, which is a pointer to `struct proto_ops`.  This is a set of function pointers, so that different types of sockets (say, Unix domain sockets, or IP sockets) can be supported in the same interface.  (Each socket type defines its own proto_ops, basically.)

net/socket.c:__sys_listen() obtains the `listen` function pointer of that set, and calls it, so that different socket types can implement their own 'listen' facility.  Because the file descriptor was already looked up, and converted to a pointer to the socket description, that pointer is passed (instead of the file descriptor).  (This same – or very similar – interface is used across all file/socket descriptor using functions.)

The core point to realize here is that file descriptor numbers are just indexes to a process-specific table of references to file descriptions.  For sockets, that reference is of type `struct sock *`.  (The table of file descriptions is internal to the kernel, and is usually called *file table*; the process-specific table of references is usually called *file descriptor table*; and a file descriptor is an index to the file descriptor table.  If you find this confusing, read e.g. the Wikipedia [File descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) article for further details.)